# Angular: Returning objects' contents from looking up its index through an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently I have a list of games I'm showing in my view, this way:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in data | filter:search" href="#/tab/ncaaf/{{gameid}}">
```

I now need to create a view that shows information from that object only. So I think I need to lookup the gameid from the array and return its contents to my template so that my individual view (when you click in from the list) can render:

```
<div class="logo" style="background-image: url({{['awayteam']['src']}});">
```

In my **controller**, I am defining the gameid as the object's index attribute.

```
$scope.gameid = data['results']['collection1'][0]['index'];
```

How do I take that gameid, go through the array, and display the contents of the object with the matching gameid on that individual view?

Comment: short answer is ...yes. See the  docs for router you are using on how to access the id value

Answer (score 0):

When configuring your app's routes with $routeProvider, you can define parameters to be received from the url by the view's controller:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/tab/ncaaf/:gameid', {
    templateUrl: '<your_view_html_path_here>'
  })
```

Then, in the controller of this view, you can receive this parameter by doing:

```
var param = $routeParams.gameId;
```

after having defined $routeParams as a dependency of the controller, of course. After this, you can  call a method in your backend passing the gameId and retrieve the game's details.

More info: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Thank you for the start. The backend passing gameId / receiving game details was really where I'm stumped. Does this belong in the controller?

Comment: I like to use services when interacting with the backend, so the controller can be free of any logic. You could create a service that uses Angular's $http service (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) in order to perform a GET operation in your backend and retrieve the data you need.